# Sort a dictionary into two different lists based on group

Tags: sorting, dictionary

import requests
from operator import itemgetter

```
foods = [{'name': 'Daisy' , 'group': 'A', 'eating': 'yes', 'feasting': 'yes', 'fasting': 'no', 'sleeping': 'no'},
      {'name': 'Donny', 'group': 'B', 'eating': 'maybe', 'feasting':'maybe', 'fasting':'maybe', 'sleeping': 'maybe'},
      {'name': 'Dwane', 'group': 'A', 'eating': 'no', 'feasting':'yes', 'fasting': 'no', 'sleeping': 'yes'},
      {'name': 'Diana', 'group': 'B', 'eating': 'never', 'feasting':'never', 'fasting':'never', 'sleeping':'never'}]


def main():
    group = sorted(foods, key=itemgetter('group'))
    group_a = []
    group_b = []
    print(group)

main()
```

Hi there, I need help with the next step of this code. I would like to place the two dictionaries with group "A" in the empty list group_a. I would also like to place the two dictionaries with group "B" in the empty list group_b.

I am not sure how to go about this. Previously I tried:

```
for row in foods:
    if 'A' in row:
        group_a.append(row)
    else:
        group_b.append(row)
```

How ever that did not work.

Does anyone have an idea of how to populate these two empty lists according to group?

Comment: I figured it out with some help from comp lists.

Comment: [item for item in group if item['group']=="D"]